# Apache Beam: Exceptions after upgrade to 2.5.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-api-client

Java version: 8
Runner: Dataflow

Everything worked before I upgrade to beam 2.5.0. Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:150)
    at com.geotab.bigdata.streaming.mapserver.backfill.MapServerBatchBeamApplication.main(MapServerBatchBeamApplication.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder.setBatchPath(Storage.java:9307)
    at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Builder.<init>(Storage.java:9286)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.Transport.newStorageClient(Transport.java:95)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil$GcsUtilFactory.create(GcsUtil.java:96)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil$GcsUtilFactory.create(GcsUtil.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getGcsUtil(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(GcsPathValidator.java:88)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:61)
```

my gradle config:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-reference-parent:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.beam:beam-runners-reference-java:2.5.0'
    compile ('org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }

    compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0') {
        force = true //version 1.23.0 causes HTTP response 404 not found exception in Beam 
       //Is this still the case?  Which version should I use with beam 2.5.0?
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    compile 'com.typesafe:config:1.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5'
}
```

Side questions are:

1. Which google-api-client version is compatible with beam 2.5?
2. Which com.google.guava:guava version is compatible for beam and google-api-client?

Comment: I have always been using _api-client_ 1.23.0 with beam 2.5 and have never noticed unexpected `404 not found exception`, although that might just be good luck.
You might want to provide us with the part of your code that launches the error, in case it's not due to a dependency issue, but a function whose parameters/... have changed

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Dataflow SDK 2.5.0 for Java has the following compile and [runtime dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#dataflow-2x-java):

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------+
|        GroupId        |     ArtifactId    |  Version |
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------+
| com.google.api-client | google-api-client |   1.23.0 |
| com.google.guava      | guava             |     20.0 |
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that AbstractGoogleClient.Builder is missing. Checking the documentation for the google-api-java-client versions, this was present in 1.19 and 1.20, but from 1.21 onward is not to be found.

According to [this GitHub issue report](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/325), updating to at least 1.23 solves those kinds of problems. Note also this comment from Nilson Pontello: "You must make a clean build after changing from 1.22.0 to 1.23.0 otherwise old libs will still be used, specially if you are generating war files using maven."